# Django post function : split method is a good way?

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, django

I'm working on my `Django` project and I'm trying to develop this one with 'Class Based View' (CBV) method in order to keep the code maintainable.

I have a class named `FreepubHome` with some methods and a very important `post` method. I would like to split this method into three methods and I don't know how I can do that.

This post method let to:

- fill and submit the form
- create a token
- send an e-mail

So I would like to get a post function which let to fill and submit my form, call the token method and the sending method.

It's very important for me to understand the process, the methodology and how I can do that in order to simplify others methods that are very important.

This is my class :

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.views.generic import CreateView

import hashlib

from .models import Publication, Document, Download

class FreepubHomeView(CreateView):
    """ Render the home page """

    template_name = 'freepub/index.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['document_list'] = Document.objects.all().order_by('publication__category__name')
        return super(FreepubHomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def create_token(self, arg1, arg2, datetime):
        # Create token based on some arguments
        plain = arg1 + arg2 + str(datetime.now())
        token = hashlib.sha1(plain.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        return token

    @staticmethod
    def increment(model):
        model.nb_download = model.nb_download + 1
        return model.save()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        document_choice = request.POST.getlist('DocumentChoice')

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.form_class(request.POST)

            for checkbox in document_choice:
                document_edqm_id = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox).edqm_id
                publication_title = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox).publication.title
                email = request.POST['email']

                token = self.create_token(email, document_edqm_id, datetime)

                Download.objects.create(email=email, pub_id=checkbox, token=token)

                document_link = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox).upload #gives media/file
                document_link2 = Download.objects.get(token = token).pub_id #gives document id

                print(document_link)
                print(document_link2)

                context = {'document_link': document_link,
                           'publication_title': publication_title}

                if form.is_valid():
                    message = get_template('freepub/message.txt').render(context)
                    html_message = get_template('freepub/message.html').render(context)
                    subject = 'EDQM HelpDesk and Publications registration'

                    mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, 'freepub@edqm.eu', [email])
                    mail.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
                    #mail.attach_file(document_link.path)  # Add attachement
                    mail.send(fail_silently=False)
                    print('Email envoyé à ' + email)

                    messages.success(request, str(
                        publication_title) + '\n' + 'You will receive an e-mail with your access to ' + document_edqm_id)

                    # Update number of downloads for document and publication
                    document = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox)
                    document = self.increment(document)

                    publication_id = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox).publication.id
                    publication = Publication.objects.get(id=publication_id)
                    publication = self.increment(publication)

                else:
                    print('form invalid')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('freepub-home')
```

These are the classes in models.py: (Not for review)

> ```
> class Document(models.Model):
>
>     FORMAT_CHOICES = (
>         ('pdf', 'PDF'),
>         ('epub', 'ePUB'),
>     )
>
>     LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
>         ('FR', 'FR'),
>         ('EN', 'EN'),
>     )
>     edqm_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name=_('publication ID'), unique=True, default='')
>     language = models.CharField(max_length=2, verbose_name=_('language'), choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, null=False)
>     format = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('format'), choices=FORMAT_CHOICES, null=False)
>     title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('document title'), null=False)
>     publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication, verbose_name=_('publication title'), null=False, related_name='documents')
>     upload = models.FileField(upload_to='media/', validators=[validate_file_extension])
>     creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('creation date'), null=False)
>     modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('modification date'), null=False)
>     nb_download = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('number of download'), default=0)
>
>
>     class Meta:
>         verbose_name = _('document')
>         verbose_name_plural = _('document')
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return f"{self.edqm_id} : {self.title}"
>
>
> class Download(models.Model):
>     email = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_('e-mail'), null=False)
>     pub = models.ForeignKey(Document, verbose_name=_('document'), null=False)
>     token = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name=_('download token'), unique=True, null=False)
>     download_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('download date'), null=False)
>     expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('expiration date'), null=False)
>     nb_download = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('usage'), default=0)
>
>     class Meta:
>         verbose_name = _('download')
>         verbose_name_plural = _('download')
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return f"{self.email} : {self.token}"
> ```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review! I’m not sure you’re asking the right kind of question for this site. Are you only asking "how do I split my method in three?" in which case this may be off-topic here, or are you asking for general improvements and think that splitting the method in three is the way to go?

Comment: Thank you @MathiasEttinger with your answer. Your question is very good because it's a bit both of them. If it was "How do Isplit my method in three", I should ask this question on stackoverflow I think. So it's rather the second part from your question. I would like to now if it's interessant to split my method in three and if you could help me to improve my post function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't know Django and so some aspects of my review may be wrong)

1. I first removed most of your functions, as things like `increment` aren't really that helpful.
   It also leaves your code with everything in one place, so that when you try to improve it you can see everything.
2. I then used guard clauses to reduce the amount of indentation `post` needs.

   Take the following change for example, with it you know that you only perform actions on post requests. Where with your code it would take longer to know that.

   ```
   if request.method != 'POST':
       return HttpResponseRedirect(self.SUCCESSFUL_URL)
   ```
3. Assuming `Document.objects.get(id=checkbox)` doesn't have any side effects, then I'd just make it a variable.
4. I would reduce the amount of variables you have. Most of your lines of code were just variables that are used once.

   ```
   # Original
   context = {'publication_title': Document.objects.get(id=checkbox).publication.title}

   # With (3)
   context = {'publication_title': document.publication.title}
   ```

   With (3) all you have to do is add `document` to your variable, and it removes a line of code. And so it improves readability at the expense of having to write `document` a couple more times.
5. I'd hope Django objects support `+=` and so you can change `increment` to use it.

   ```
   model.nb_download += 1
   ```
6. I'd make a function `email` that takes a couple of arguments but performs all `EmailMultiAlternatives` and `get_template` handling.

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.views.generic import CreateView

import hashlib

from .models import Publication, Document, Download


def gen_token(*values):
    plain = ''.join([str(i) for i in values] + [str(datetime.now())])
    return hashlib.sha1(plain.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()


class FreepubHomeView(CreateView):
    """ Render the home page """

    template_name = 'freepub/index.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm
    SUCCESSFUL_URL = reverse('freepub-home')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['document_list'] = Document.objects.all().order_by('publication__category__name')
        return super(FreepubHomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def email(self, email, upload, title, edqm_id):
        context = {
            'document_link': upload,
            'publication_title': title
        }
        subject = 'EDQM HelpDesk and Publications registration'
        message = get_template('freepub/message.txt').render(context)
        mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, 'freepub@edqm.eu', [email])
        html_message = get_template('freepub/message.html').render(context)
        mail.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
        #mail.attach_file(document.upload.path)  # Add attachement
        mail.send(fail_silently=False)
        print('Email envoyé à ' + email)
        messages.success(request, str(title) + '\n' + 'You will receive an e-mail with your access to ' + edqm_id)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method != 'POST':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.SUCCESSFUL_URL)

        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        email = request.POST['email']
        for checkbox in request.POST.getlist('DocumentChoice'):
            document = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox)
            token = gen_token(email, document.edqm_id)
            Download.objects.create(email=email, pub_id=checkbox, token=token)
            if not form.is_valid():
                print('form invalid')
                continue
            self.email(email, document.upload, document.publication.title, document.eqdm_id)
            document.nb_download += 1
            document.save()
            publication = Publication.objects.get(id=document.publication.id)
            publication.nb_download += 1
            publication.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.SUCCESSFUL_URL)
```

Comment: _"I'd hope Django objects support += and so you can change increment to use it."_ In fact, for such simple updates, you can also do it all in the database without retrieving the objects in the Python world: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1599090/5069029

Comment: Very good job @Peilonrayz ! I agree with you for lots of modifications ! It's better mainly with `document` variable which is called just one time by the queryset. I had too many variables called one time and you solved that. I like the email function and I don't know why I didn't overcome to do that ...It works fine, it's clear. I don't modify `SUCCESSFUL_URL` because I believe with Django `CreateView` it's better to define `success_url` by a function. 

Point 1 : I'm ok !

Point 2 : It's ok, but I keep my `success_url` function

Point 3 to 6 : I'm ok

Thank you so much !